# Export contents of SQLite table and import it in php myAdmin table

Tags: sqlite, import, phpmyadmin, export-to-csv

I am having a database table in sqlite which is having data.
Now I have tried to export that table and import in phpmyadmin database in `.csv` format.
But there are some problems with some `NOT NULL`.

Sqlite side create query :

```
 CREATE TABLE StateDeathTax_V2 (Sequence Integer DEFAULT TEXT,Question,Alabama,Alaska,Arizona,Arkansas,California,Colorado,Connecticut,Delaware,"District of Columbia" TEXT DEFAULT NULL,Florida,Georgia,Hawaii,Idaho,Illinois,Indiana,Iowa,Kansas,Kentucky,Louisiana,Maine,Maryland,Massachusetts,Michigan,Minnesota,Mississippi,Missouri,Montana,Nebraska,Nevada,"New Hampshire" TEXT DEFAULT NULL,"New Jersey" TEXT DEFAULT NULL,"New Mexico" TEXT,"New York" TEXT DEFAULT NULL,"North Carolina" TEXT DEFAULT NULL,"North Dakota" TEXT DEFAULT NULL,Ohio,Oklahoma,Oregon,Pennsylvania,"Rhode Island" TEXT DEFAULT NULL,"South Carolina" TEXT,"South Dakota" TEXT DEFAULT NULL,Tennessee,Texas,Utah,Vermont,Virginia,Washington,"West Virginia" TEXT DEFAULT NULL,Wisconsin,Wyoming)
```

Error :

```
SQL query:

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `roster`.`TABLE 4` (`Sequence` int(1), `Question` varchar(56), `Alabama` varchar(66), `Alaska` varchar(68), `Arizona` varchar(196), `Arkansas` varchar(114), `California` varchar(78), `Colorado` varchar(83), `Connecticut` varchar(463), `Delaware` varchar(295), `District of Columbia` varchar(392), `Florida` varchar(92), `Georgia` varchar(66), `Hawaii` varchar(274), `Idaho` varchar(107), `Illinois` varchar(626), `Indiana` varchar(253), `Iowa` varchar(337), `Kansas` varchar(153), `Kentucky` varchar(216), `Louisiana` varchar(96), `Maine` varchar(1029), `Maryland` varchar(358), `Massachusetts` varchar(867), `Michigan` varchar(76), `Minnesota` varchar(470), `Mississippi` varchar(64), `Missouri` varchar(77), `Montana` varchar(79), `Nebraska` varchar(151), `Nevada` varchar(79), `New Hampshire` varchar(69), `New Jersey` varchar(775), `New Mexico` varchar(17), `New York` varchar(747), `North Carolina` varchar(73), `North Dakota` varchar(1366), `Ohio` varchar(509), `Okla[...]

MySQL said: Documentation
#1060 - Duplicate column name 'NULL'
```

Comment: Please post the schema of your table and the details about how you export it.

Comment: I can create table with this name and column names in phpmyadmin, but how can I import all data in this table?

Comment: I have created it in sqlite table.Data is in sqlite table. I want to copy it in phpmyadmin sql table.

Answer (score 0):

1. Confirm that the table you created in sqlite has data and looks good.
2. From sqlite, do the following:

   `sqlite> .header on
   sqlite> .mode csv 
   sqlite> .output data.csv 
   sqlite> select * from StateDeathTax_V2 ; 
   sqlite> .quit`
3. Confirm the data is exported correctly by checking the file `data.csv`
4. Import, see answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9734486/importing-a-csv-into-phpmyadmin