# Convert Text File To MySQL Database

Tags: mysql

I have .txt file that is about 20MB in size. Each Line looks like the following.

```
*,00000000,Binary Zero,Description
*,00000001,Binary One,Description
*,00000010,Binary Two,Description
*,00000011,Binary Three,Description
*,00000100,Binary Four,Description
*,00000101,Binary Five,Description
*,00000110,Binary Six,Description
*,00000111,Binary Seven,Description
*,00001000,Binary Eight,Description
*,00001001,Binary Nine,Description
*,00001010,Binary Ten,Description
```

What I want to do is convert it to mysql database where the astericks will be replaced with an auto increment number called id. And the commas would be where a new field starts. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: phpmyadmin can convert a csv file into a mysql db

Comment: @SethCohen Have any examples or tutorials on how to do this with phpmyadmin with csv in that exact format?

Comment: dunno about fo ryour exact situation, but see this s0 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9734486/importing-a-csv-into-phpmyadmin check that out, play around with phpmyadmin

Answer (score 1):

If it would be me, I'd make a ruby script to convert that thing in a .sql with a list of INSERT statements. The only actual issue seems to be the asterisk, that should become an auto key...

So, first of all, you have to create a table in your database. Let's say you do

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable(
  ID INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  Binary CHAR(whatever)
  Name VARCHAR(whatever),
  Description VARCHAR(whatever)
)
```

Then, you can make a .sql with some scripting language.

Maybe you can even do it with a .sh bash (`sed -i -E 's/^\*,([^,]+),([^,]+),(.+)$/INSERT INTO MyTable (Binary, Name, Description) VALUES ("\1", "\2", "\3");/'`)

Otherwise, i feel more comfortable with Ruby:

```
require 'csv'
CSV.foreach("your_file.txt") do |row|
  puts <<EOS
INSERT INTO MyTable (Binary, Name, Description) VALUES ("#{row[1]}", "#{row[2]}", "#{row[3]}");
EOS
end
```

this will output a list of insert statements, that you can redirect to a file and feed to the SQL server (you can also write to file directly from the ruby script, or send commands to the SQL server directly from the Ruby script.

Comment: I love your Answer but I didn't get it until doing what @Seth Cohen recomeneded ;)

Answer (score 1):

Create your table then use [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) in MySQL.

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable(
  ID INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  binary VARCHAR(8),
  name VARCHAR(45),
  description TINYTXT
)
```

Open the file in excel, open office, or something like that, then replace all of the `*` characters with an empty field.

Then use:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.csv' INTO TABLE db2.my_table;
```

You can download [MySQL Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/tools/workbench/5.2.html) and it's a lot *safer* than using PHPMyAdmin. *Provided you're doing something like using SSH to connect and you have no external accounts for MySQL open (so you have to be serverside).

Answer (score 1):

mysql itself can [import csv files](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlimport.html):

```
mysqlimport --fields-optionally-enclosed-by=""" --fields-terminated-by=, --lines-terminated-by="\r\n" --user=YOUR_USERNAME --password YOUR_DATABASE YOUR_TABLE.csv
```

Do let me know if you have further problems.