# Workflow for getting data collected in the field into relational database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, import

**Context:** I'm a field ecology grad student. In our lab we often collect data in the field in a notebook and, when we return from the field, we need to get it into digital form. The standard in our lab is to enter everything in a flat Excel table, but this is error prone and the data are hard to work with after. There is some interest in our lab for migrating to MySQL to store data and the main issue is getting the data from a flat format in a notebook into a corresponding set of MySQL tables. I've been tasked with teaching the lab how to do this because I have some SQL experience already.

**Simplified Example:** We live trap for small mammals of various species at various sites and take measurements. We typically have on the order of 100 measurements at a time. We have 3 SQL tables for the data: one corresponding to site information (e.g. habitat, lat/long, etc.), one corresponding to species information (taxonomy, dental formula, etc.) and one storing the measurements of individual animals (weight, length, etc.).

The solution needs to be fairly easy to implement for people who aren't super technical. For example, creating a web form is probably too complicated, though if there's an easy way to do this I'd be open to it. Also, it should be possible to enter large amounts of data at once. Finally, it should be pretty easy to set up for new datasets because we're often designing new studies and needing to collect different types of data.

Comment: Maybe this is interesting to you: http://fusion.cs.uni-jena.de/bexis | Disclaimer: It's a project of some colleagues of mine.

Comment: Just an idea, not sure it's suits you- you can use [phpMyAdmin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpMyAdmin) ([official site](http://www.phpmyadmin.net))to just insert the data directly. 
Also, assuming people are already used to it- you can copy the data to a csv file and then [import it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9734486/) to the database.
just make sure you prevent some privileges by setting up a special user.