# Copy and Paste Data into PhpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

after searching the internet for a bit, I'm pretty sure this hasn't been answered directly so I'm asking here.

I am currently creating a Runescape (Laugh at me all you want ;P) Skilling Calculator for a School Programming Project, and am creating databases for XP values with phpMyAdmin, using information that is already on the web.
Instead of having to manually type out approximately 6000 different entries, each with 3 columns, I would rather copy and paste them, alleviating both time, and chances for errors. For example, I want to copy and paste all the information from here:

http://www.tip.it/runescape/pages/view/divination_calc.htm onto phpMyAdmin in bulk; not one entry at a time. I was wondering if this was possible in any way.

Comment: Paste Data into phpmyadmin? What does that mean? I'm assuming that you just want that table data put into a database. Where's the code that shows you tried? You probably want to scrape the page with PHP's DOMDocument and use mysqli or PDO to enter data into a MySQL Database. So, you have to know HTML, PHP and MySQL at the bare minimum to do this. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Yes, I want to essentially copy and paste the data from the table on the website to my database, whilst still keeping the formatting (The Method on one column, the level on the next, and the xp the last column). 
I have honestly no idea how to go about doing this, having had no prior experience with Databases, so I don't have any code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest copying and pasting the HTML table into excel, tidying up columns to match your database, saving as a CSV and importing using PHPMyAdmin's import function.

Here's an article I found on importing a CSV into PHPMyAdmin: [importing a CSV into phpmyadmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9734486/importing-a-csv-into-phpmyadmin)

Comment: That is an excellent suggestion, I'm not sure why I didn't think of this beforehand, thanks!

Comment: That's not automated. But if it works for you that's great.