# Where should my .csv file be to be imported into my MYSQL database with XAMP?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I am trying to insert in my database the data contained in a .csv file. I am using XAMP. I dont know where I have to locate or configure the path in order to make MySQL find the file.

Comment: By default it's located under localhost/phpmyadmin, which if I am correct you can simply access via root username with no password.  From there you can import it to your table via the `Import` tab. Or is this not what you meant?

Comment: If my file is in that directory phpmyadmin will be able to locate it? I have to execute: LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'Data.csv'

Comment: doesn't matter you can simply upload the file like you would when submitting a form, just login to phpmyadmin it will do the rest for you.

Comment: Otherwise it's duplicate of this I believe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9734486/importing-a-csv-into-phpmyadmin

Comment: No, becouse I have my sql statement, the csv it is not going to be imported directly with myphpadmin

Comment: Ok, then you can use absolute path to the csv file e.g: `LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/www/csv/data.csv'` or whatever the path may be. Depending on your file location e.g: `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/to/your/local/file' INTO TABLE yourtable` Hope this helps.

Comment: For Windows I believe this should work: `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE  "C:\\Users\sergi\Desktop\file.csv"` note the double quotes. Hope this helps.

Comment: It shows me: Can't find file 'C:\UserssergiDesktopData.csv'.

Comment: Looks like it's stripping the backward slashes, could you try with a forward slash?

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Thank you so much!

Comment: Perfect, glad it worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "C://Users/sergi/Desktop/file.csv"
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to localhost/phpmyadmin create a database and select that database you will find "Import" option on the top left right navbar of phpmyadmin and then follow the guide and upload your .csv file.
[Have a look at this tutorial](https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/phpmyadmin/import-database-using-phpmyadmin/)

Answer (score 0):

1. Upload .csv file in public_html via ftp.
2. Access your phpmyadmin -> Select database -> Click on SQL tab.
3. Type following SQL query.
        load data local infile ‘Full path for .CSV file’ into table city
        fields terminated by ‘,’
        enclosed by ‘”‘lines terminated by ‘\n’
        Replace actual full path with “Full path for .CSV file” (/home        /username/public_html/filename.csv)
4. now you are ready to rock by clicking GO