# Failing to import a CSV into PhpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, database, csv, phpmyadmin

Im trying to get data from an sql server Database into a PHPMyAdmin Databse. Most of my attempts have failed in every way. Creating a Script, using MysqlWorkbench, etc.

So I decided maybe I could just recreate a table in PHPMyAdmin manually, dump the Sql Server Data into a .csv file and import it into my PHPMyAdmin Table. If that works I could technically recreate the whole databse manually.

Well this is where my main problem lies. Im sure some of you thought my question would be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9734486/importing-a-csv-into-phpmyadmin) one.

Well every result that comes up in my google search says something along the lines of:

"My .csv look like this: data, data, data, data, data, etc."

Well my .csv looks like this:

[image]

Im slightly confused as to what Im exactly doing wrong? Where should I put the seperators? Am I looking at it wrong? Should I use another application to open the csv file instead of excel?

Because if I try to import the file in its current state I get hit with an error "Invalid amount of columns in CSV-Import Row 1". Which apparently indicates that theres no seperators that PhpMyAdmin can recognize.

Does anybody see what Im doing wrong?

Comment: You should open the CSV with notepad, then you can see the separators

Comment: @Marged Just as I was writing my own answer! But thank you nonetheless!

Comment: Oh Im new here and Im trying my best to adapt. What exactly would be the words and topics I talk about, that are not that liked on here?

Comment: @Marged Oooh yess. That mightve been a hasty decision. I see you noticed that I made my first contact with the "But why do you do it this way?" user on Stackoverflow. I heard theyre a common occurence around here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I received a downvote and assumed, that if somebody is willing to downvote me this quickly, I just didnt look hard enough on google.

So I went back to googling around and found an article that explains the most common .csv problems.

And one of them was that people open the file in excel and see the data and are confused as to why they dont seem to have the same file as everybody else.

So I had a "lightbulb over my head" moment and opened the file in Editor and there my missing seperators were.

Sorry for making an unnecessary post.