# how to manualy import csv into mysql

Tags: mysql, csv, phpmyadmin

is there a way to manually import csv file to mysql phpmyadmin ?
like I have a csv file with sentences inside and I want it to be imported into a table with more than one column ID, SENTENCES, Length.

I want the csv to go to SENTENCES column in that table. is that doable manually ?

Comment: Are you aware of https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html

Comment: Already answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9734486/importing-a-csv-into-phpmyadmin.  You have to import to a temp table, and then insert new rows using the temp table.  Other MySQL client tools have mapping capabilities that are nicer.  Sequel Pro is one you can look at that is also free/donateware